# When inserting DOM element from JavaScript, CSS styles are not displayed

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, dom

I want to display a log with a title and a content.

With the following code, `li` elements are inserted in the DOM with the right `className` but styles are not displayed.

This is inside an Angular Component, which I think may be the origin of the error. It's just a basic new app with html: `<app-example></app-example>`

Note: if I insert an element by hand in the html it is displayed correctly.
The only difference I notice is that `li` elements inserted from javascript do not have `_ngcontent-cxr-c40`.

Html:

```html
<ul class="d-flex f-column log-list" id="log-list">
        <li id="log-item" class="log-message">
          <span class="log-message-title">TEST</span>
        </li>
</ul>
```

This is the function to add an element to the log:

```js
  private addLogElement(title: string, message: string): void {
    const newNode = document.createElement('li');
    newNode.className = 'log-message';
    const newNodeTitle = document.createElement('span');
    newNodeTitle.className = 'log-message-title';

    const headerText = document.createTextNode(title);

    newNodeTitle.appendChild(headerText);
    newNode.appendChild(newNodeTitle);

    const parentDiv = document.getElementById('log-list');
    const childDiv = document.getElementById('log-item');
    parentDiv.insertBefore(newNode, childDiv);
  }
```

Comment: Your code should work, but it's not an "Angular way". Use an array and a *ngFor over this array:https://angular.io/guide/structural-directives, you only need add an element to the array

Comment: Yes, you shouldn't be directly modifying the document like that. Take a data-driven approach instead.

Comment: There is likely some benefit to using renderer2 when manipulating the dom, but it should work with just JS. Check out
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/angular-using-renderer2
for more info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use Renderer2 API for such DOM Manipulations.

In Component class in constructor inject it like :-

```
constructor(public renderer: Renderer2) {}
```

Then change your method to :-

```
private addLogElement(title: string, message: string): void {
    const newNode = this.renderer.createElement('li');
    this.renderer.addClass(newNode, 'log-message');
    const newNodeTitle = this.renderer.createElement('span');
    this.renderer.addClass(newNodeTitle, 'log-message-title');
    const headerText = this.renderer.createText(title);
    this.renderer.appendChild(newNodeTitle, headerText);
    this.renderer.appendChild(newNode, newNodeTitle);

    const parentDiv = this.renderer.selectRootElement(document.getElementById('log-list'), true);
    const childDiv = this.renderer.selectRootElement(document.getElementById('log-item'), true);
    this.renderer.insertBefore(parentDiv, newNode, childDiv);
  }
```

There are other reasons why you should use Renderer2 instead of native DOM manipulation.

You can refer to those reasons here :- https://medium.com/dev-genius/dont-use-native-dom-manipulations-in-angular-6c8db13f463f

Answer (score -1):

Add this in your `css/scss` 
I have added sample styles

```
:host ::ng-deep .log-message{
    color: red;
}
:host ::ng-deep .log-message-title{
    background-color: #eeee33
}
```